# Restricting product quantity field to numbers only in Gravity Forms

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

How can i restrict the product quantity field to numbers only in Gravity Forms.

And how can we add some increment arrow to the quantity field?

like on this demo ? http://demos.gravitywiz.com/gp-conditional-pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David from Gravity Wiz.

He gave me the hint that i just need to enabled HTML5 on the Gravity Forms global settings page.

Can't believe i missed that setting.

Answer (score 0):

The increment arrows are inherent in `<input type="number">`, your browser automatically adds them.

When you're setting up your form you just use the 'number' input rather than a 'text' input.

So instead of `<input type="text" id="field_id" name="field_name" value="" />`, what you want to use is something akin to:

`<input type="number" id="field_id" name="field_name" value="" step="1"/>`

You can see the various attributes that can be set/specified for number inputs here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp

Comment: Thanks for all the infos Tony! 
Is there a easy way, a filter or function I can use to change the attribute type from „text“ to „number“ in gravity forms ?

Comment: The easy way would be to go to the form in Gravity Forms and change the type of input. I don’t use GF but I’d imagine they have a number input option.  Any hung other than that would be unnecessary extra work.  Unless I’m missing something.